# Converting .ichat files into human readable form

Tags: xml, plist, imessage

I want to convert chat messages in `.ichat` files (archived macOS Messages chats) into a human readable form, something as follows. (My conversations are all one-on-one to simplify things!)

- (13:40) Me: Hello
- (13:41) You: How are you?
- (13:41) Me: Great, Thanks...

There seems to be no existing utilities that do this, so I thought to write my own, but the format is cryptic to put it mildly, and I haven't been able to find any relevant documentation.

The files are full of strange `CF$UID` entries and just an occasional few entries are the actual text messages, with no obvious way to tell which person said what.

Here is a snippet that outlines the format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>$archiver</key>
    <string>NSKeyedArchiver</string>
    <key>$objects</key>
    <array>
        <string>$null</string>
        <dict>
            <key>$class</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CF$UID</key>
                <integer>73</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>NS.objects</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CF$UID</key>
                    <integer>2</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>CF$UID</key>
                    <integer>3</integer>
                </dict>
...
    <dict>
        <key>$class</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CF$UID</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>NS.string</key>
        <string>Hello, World!</string>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

These plists are in the NSKeyedArchiver format, which is explained in this 2016 blog post: [Manual Analysis of ‘NSKeyedArchiver’ Formatted Plist Files](https://www.mac4n6.com/blog/2016/1/1/manual-analysis-of-nskeyedarchiver-formatted-plist-files-a-review-of-the-new-os-x-1011-recent-items). In short, the array associated with the `$objects` key contains an ordered list of objects, and the hexadecimal bytes scattered throughout the plist in `<string>` tags are indexes into that list. The top-level object is identified in the dictionary associated with the `$top` key.

[unarchive-plist](https://github.com/whyallyn/unarchive-plist) is a Python script for converting these plists into a more intelligible format, but it only works on macOS.

Comment: Finally someone had something to say about this... I haven't dug through the material yet, but I assume the answer will be at the end of the tunnel. I'll write back when I've tried this... "Ugh Why!?" indeed...

Comment: @forthrin What OS are you on? I needed to read some of these files on Windows, and I found your question while trying to figure out how to do it. I ended up writing a PowerShell script that throws away most of the metadata and produces a JSON object with the critical details (message text, sender, recipients, date), so if that would be helpful, I could probably clean it up, put it on GitHub, and edit my answer.

Comment: I'm on macOS. Doesn't unarchive-plist produce an understandable output?

Comment: Presumably, but it 'must be run on an OS X system with Xcode installed as it utilizes PyObjC (the bridge between Python and Objective-C) for Apple specific classes and objects,' and I didn't have a Mac to hand.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can just unarchive the files using NSKeyedUnarchiver. You'll need to step through the unarchiving process in the debugger to get to the required keys and custom classes used in the archive.

P.S.: I've built an app for that: [Past](https://zeezide.de/en/products/past/)